# How can I add a property on Form and see it on object inspector?

Tags: forms, delphi, customization, object-inspector

I read in some articles but nothing helped me. I tried put on my Form the property as published and I tried use the procedure Regiter and RegisterCustomModule, but nothing was resolved.

Comment: You put the form into a design time package right?

Comment: Huh, what happened to the need of 5 close-voters?

Comment: @NGLN Some members are designated as subject experts or something like that and have the ability to close tickets in their realm of expertise automatically. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders

Comment: @Gray Ok, thanks. I'll be more considerate then!

Comment: @NGLN you just wielded your Dupehammer

Comment: Yes, I followed the post that @NGLN mentioned, but nothing happened

Comment: Did you put your code in a design time package and install it into the IDE?

Comment: I guess you did it wrong. But you gave no details. So we can hardly be expected to repeat all the standard advice.